# Sendgrid outgoing email to appear in my Sent Mailbox

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, sendgrid

I am currently sending emails using sendgrid:

```
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'david@gmail.com'
    email = EmailMessage(subject, message, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAILS)
    email.send()
```

However, when I go to my sent mail box in Gmail, that email does not show. Is there a way such that when I send an email from Sendgrid, it will show up in my sent mail box on Gmail, to keep a record of it?

Comment: This isn't really possible. When you send the email it uses SMTP directly to sendgrid. When you send via Google they will automatically add it to your outbox. To do the same when someone else sends the message you would have to manually place a copy of the sent message in your outbox using IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendGrid's [BCC app](https://sendgrid.com/app/appSettings/type/bcc/id/14) will allow you to BCC an email address, in this case your gmail account, with every email sent; though you still can't filter it to sent mail. The documentation for it can be found [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/bcc.html).